# Can hand sanitizer kill a fertilized human egg cell?

Tags: cell-biology, development, alcohol, eggs, gamete

If you took a human egg cell that was fertilized in vitro and sprayed some hand sanitizer on it would it die?

Comment: Hello and Welcome at Biology SE! Please take our [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to ask good questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most likely.  Alcohol-based hand sanitizers are [at least 60% alcohol](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3291447/) (ethanol or isopropanol).  Alcohol concentrations as low as 15% are efficient at killing cultured mammalian cells.

See: [Toxicity of Ethanol in Low Concentrations: Experimental Evaluation in Cell Culture](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8995467/)

> All cells were killed by a 15-s exposure to 30-40% ethanol while a concentration as low as 15-20% gave a total response after 5-10-min exposures.